# How to set time zone for calendar event programmatically?

Tags: java, android

In android app, while inserting calendar event, how to set time zone for that inserting calendar event. Any help is really appreciated and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

you can create a Calender instance.

```
 public static Date getDate(Date date,TimeZone zone){

   Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance(zone);  
    cal.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());  

    Calendar output = Calendar.getInstance();  

    output.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, first.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); 
    output.set(Calendar.MONTH, first.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    output.set(Calendar.YEAR, first.get(Calendar.YEAR)); 
    output.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, first.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));  
    output.set(Calendar.MINUTE, first.get(Calendar.MINUTE));  
    output.set(Calendar.SECOND, first.get(Calendar.SECOND));  
    output.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, first.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));  

    return output.getTime();
```

}

Comment: does it get the current location's time zone?

Comment: the date passed is in UTC, and the time zone passed is the desired Time Zone.This method Changes a date in UTC to another timezone.
You can get the date in UTC by subtracting the offset of the current location's time zone.                                            TimeZone userTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(usertimeZoneId);
  return new Date(userdate.getTime() - userTimeZone.getRawOffset());

Comment: Use  getDefault() to get TimeZone